# AppStore downloaded wrong version of iOS App

Tags: ios, app-store, version

I develop a single iOS app and noticed something last night that I'd never seen before.  I had an adhoc development version of the app on my phone and wanted to show someone the version posted on the AppStore.  I deleted my local version, went to the AppStore, which correctly showed 1.1.0, but then when I downloaded it an older version 1.0.9.9 was installed.  I knew it right away because major UI revamps were missing.

I know there is often a lag right after releasing the app (I always use Developer Hold), but this was nearly 2 weeks after I had released the new version that suddenly the old version was downloaded.  Has anyone seen this behavior and if so, is there any real recourse?

Comment: Try to recall whether you submit the right app. If you did, try emailing them.

Comment: It was definitely the right app - the version had been posted and verified by dozens of people for over a week.

Comment: We saw this same problem and tracked it down to some weirdness with TestFlight.  I would be curious though if people had any additional info though (or if you did or didn't have TestFlight installed)....

Comment: I have never used TestFlight.